# proper url routing for seo

Tags: asp.net, routes, seo, url-routing

i use url routing for my category list and final http url is like as follows..

> sitename/en/categories/000019001002/gauges-sensor-sets

as you guess, **000019001002** part points out the category code
and **gauges-sensor-sets** part is name of the category which is most important part(for search engines).

i am doubtful about this format, should i put category code section at the and of the address like

> sitename/en/categories/gauges-sensor-sets/000019001002

what do you recommend?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd stick with what you have, with the name of the category at the end. This is what a lot of other sites do, although I doubt there is much difference in terms of SEO benefit between the two. The good thing about having the category ID first is that if the category name gets truncated the link will still work.

Have you thought about removing the ID completely and just using the category name? This is what I usually do. As long as all the names are unique this shouldn't present too many problems. It would make your URLs friendlier and may give a slight SEO boost.

Comment: +1 for the remove id comment. You only have to add the id if users use it. Depends on your branche I think. Otherwise just remove the id and retrieve your page based on name.

Comment: thanks ... but native category names are not english, 
i am converting all names from greek to english on run-time.
that's way i could not trust the names.

Comment: Fair enough. In that case I'd stick with ID then name as you currently have.